# How to lock an object within threads in C++ / CLI?

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

To simplify my problem, I have a multiple threads that accesses a single data structure containing object handles. What I want to be able to do is, if one of the threads is current reading and writing to an object, be able to lock that object from other threads that may access that object within the data structure.

So it looks something like this:

```
ref class ThreadX{
public:
    ThreadX(List<customer^>^ aList){
        this->customerDatabase = aList;
    }
    void ThreadProc(){
        // do something with thread
    }
}
private:
List<customer^>^ customerDatabase;

int main(){
    List<customer^>^ aList;
    ThreadX^ process1 = gcnew ThreadX(aList);

    Thread^ Thread1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(process1, &ThreadX::ThreadProc));
    Thread1->Name = "Thread 1";
    Thread^ Thread2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(process1, &ThreadX::ThreadProc));
    Thread2->Name = "Thread 2";
    Thread1->Start();
    Thread2->Start();
}
```

Now I will have multiple threads, but I want to be able to deny a thread accesses to an index of the `customerDatabase`. I have read that I should be able to do this with locks, but I am having a hard time figuring it out. Most of what I see if for C# and not C++/CLI. I have cut a lot of the code out to make it more readable and not just a wall of code.

Comment: std::atomic should have what you need.

Comment: If you have access to C++11 features (have not done CLI, not sure if you do) then I'd search around for Anthony Williams thread-safe linked list implementation from his book "C++ Concurrency in Action"

Comment: You are thinking about this in a very unconstructive way.  It is not possible to lock an object, you can only use locks to *block code*.  Pretty important that you educate yourself or threading is going to eat you alive.

Comment: I believe std::atomic is not compatible with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

C# lock keyword is just a wrapper around Monitor. C++\CLI sample is available as linked below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

I've copied the relevant code below.

```
void Enqueue(T qValue)
{
  // Request the lock, and block until it is obtained.
  Monitor::Enter(m_inputQueue);
  try
  {
     // When the lock is obtained, add an element.
     m_inputQueue->Enqueue(qValue);
  }
  finally
  {
     // Ensure that the lock is released.
     Monitor::Exit(m_inputQueue);
  }
};
```